# Reserved words in struts?

Tags: java, struct

I have a form field with name="attr" and if i keep the field empty and save it is getting filled up with some junk values.i would like to know that is attr a keyword in struts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](https://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl-basics.html) `#attr['foo'] or #attr.foo` is used for

> Access to PageContext if available, otherwise searches request/session/application respectively

So yeah, you should probably avoid using that name for your fields.